# Why is it said to be particularly bad to return DataTables from a web service?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, datatable, dataset

Using a non-JSON-enabled VB.Net web service (or really any web service in general), I've heard it's pretty bad to be returning DataTables.  I've read explanations on why it's bad, but all these explanations seem to have one serious flaw in common: They show why it's bad to return DataSets, not DataTables.

Those are obviously two different things.  A DataTable is mostly just data (although not completely so), whereas a DataSet, from what I understand, is much more "operation-enabled".  There are differences either way though.

So putting DataSets aside, why is it bad to return a DataTable from a web service, in particular a non-JSON-enabled VB.Net one?  Is there really any misstep in doing so, or is it just with DataSets?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way that you shouldn't return a `DataSet` because the client might not understand it, the client may not understand a `DataTable`. Why *should* it be understood by something that's not running .NET?

Comment: DataTables then are pretty exclusively .Net entities?  I guess that would make sense, but I just want to confirm it right quick.

Comment: Yes, they are .NET only. Other platforms may have similar objects, but there's no common representation of these in XML. Just send a `List<T>` where `T` is a type that contains properties for all the columns you want.

Comment: Basically the standard approach is to define your data VERY carefully because this is the "data level API". Light, and explicit. DataTables are heavy (tons of stuff noone needs in a web service scenario most of hte time) and their serialization is a implementation detail.